# I'm making a JavaScript extension for a site. I'd like to use Java or C# instead. Is it possible?

Tags: c#, java, javascript, sockets, bots

This is hard for me to explain and even harder for me to visualize how I'd do it, since I don't know the bounds of communication with websites with Java and C#, so if I banter a lot/make no sense in the process of describing this, I apologize.

Basically, I'm making a 'bot' for [www.plug.dj](http://www.plug.dj).  This bot is able to do things on command like kick users, ban users, send chat messages, delete chat messages, say random things, etc.  As of right now, it's powered by a simple one-file JavaScript code with a ton of listeners and callbacks using the Plug.dj API to handle them.  This is ALL engineered by JS -- on the back-end, I think Plug.dj is powered by Python, I could be wrong.

Anyway, what I would LIKE to do is create this bot on a language other than JS.  It's really basic and not super powerful, and there are things like communicate with databases and such that I'd like to implement that aren't possible/convenient with JS.  I just want to know if this is possible, and if so, where should I start looking?

I'd prefer a language like Java or C#.  If there's any more info you need to know in order to answer this, let me know, please!  I'd like to start working on this, I think it'd be fun to learn how to communicate with websites with Java/C#/whatever.

Comment: There are various compilers that turn C# into Javascript.

Comment: That's really not what I had in mind.  I don't want JS to be involved at all if possible.  I'm not trying to leave it because I'm not comfortable writing it, it's because I want to do things that JS restricts.

Comment: It sounds like this is not really about the choice of language, but about whether you write this bot in a browser (with the restrictions that brings) or not.

Comment: That's correct Kylotan, and I'm trying to avoid using the browser because I don't like using the JS bookmarklet nor do I like writing JS code nor do I feel like it's capable of doing what I want it to do.

Comment: @connergdavis – "nor do I like writing JS code" – this is a step best solved by shutting up and doing it anyway. It's what web browsers run, it's all web browsers will ever (for practical values of "ever") be able to run, you don't have the option of not having to write at least *some* JS if you need to run code in a browser. It's like complaining you can't get a job in the US because you're only willing to speak French. That said, the only thing that comes to mind is offloading processing to a server using AJAX calls, but you have to use JSONP or CORS to do cross-domain calls to your server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `bot` javascript runs on "their" server, then there is no simple solution.  They are providing a mechanism for running "your" javascript on their server, but the chances are that they don't support other languages.  (And the only way to find out would be to ask "them").  Assuming that the answer is "no", you would need to investigate whether you can implement your "bot"s functionality in client-side code; e.g. a custom client that you implemented from scratch in Java or C# or whatever.  That's a big "if" ... because it will only work if they expose the server functionality you need in their external APIs.

OTOH, if the `bot` javascript runs on "your" server, then you should be able to change it to support other languages.  (It wouldn't necessarily be easy though ...)

---

My advice would be to take a deep breath ... and stick with Javascript.  We all have to use languages that we don't think are "fun".

Comment: Ideally, I would like to emulate a connection to the site on a low level, and then build a framework on top of that -- the original plan with JavaScript.  I don't run the server, but I figured there'd be a way to emulate what the web browser does, without having to include a web browser in the process.  So I guess making the language emulate a socket connection and get all the data like a browser would.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @connergdavis - In *might* be possible, but it sounds like a horrendous idea.

Comment: I have seen somebody do this before and I believe WebSockets were involved, but Plug.dj may have since abandoned using them, they've been making huge updates to their backend, for example moving from AppEngine to something else.  I'll go look for that code again, it really wasn't that complex, and it worked.

Here's what I'm talking about: [on github](https://github.com/Qix-/Base-Bot/) .......  okay looking closer at it, it appears that it's a complete rewrite of the entire JavaScript code that Plug.dj put in which sounds painful and unnecessary.  I agree with you that this idea is bad XD

Answer (score 0):

I honestly would just leave it in javascript if it is something you need to have run in the client.

If you need to make database calls, you can introduce a web services layer in between against which you can make AJAX calls which interact with databases.

I think your perception of javascript as basic and not very powerful is not a very good one.  They are very complex apps build today in just javascript and HTML5.  You just might need to start looking at things like backbone.js, underscore.js, and similar libraries that can help provide more advanced code organization functionality available to you.

If however you are looking at building something that individual clients are not going to have installed in their browsers, but rather would just interact with the website in an automated admin, then certainly you can establish you own web service in whatever language you like to interact with their API's and perform admin tasks.

Answer (score 0):

If they provide a JavaScript library that runs client side, it seems likely that it will be communicating with the server over HTTP.  Therefore, it should be possible for you to analyse the library and the calls it makes to reverse engineer the server API (which would be the HTTP calls) and re-implement it in the language of your choice.

Looking at the code of `bot.js`:

https://github.com/backus/Plug.DJ-Javascript-Chatbot/blob/master/bin/bot.js

it seems everything comes down to calls against their API object, eg `API.getDJs()`, `API.getWaitList()` etc.  If you can determine how this API object works, then you might be able to reverse engineer and re-implement.